# Difference of usage between ‘право, правда, and действительно’?

Tags: словоупотребление

What is the difference in usage between them, i couldnt find anything online and правда и действительно have the same definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Правда"** means **"truth"**:

> Это правда, что он ее любит?
>   Is it true he loves her?

**"Действительно"** means **"really"**, **"actually"**:

> Он действительно ее любит?
>   Does he really love her?

**"Право"** in this context is a somewhat outdated word:

> Я право не знаю, любит ли он ее.
>   I don't really know if he loves her.

Of course, I've described only the meaning of each of these words, in which they can be applied in a similar context.
In reality, every word in this list has many other meanings and applications.

Comment: In the example i was given for “право: да, ты право света но это моё дело, meaning your right but thats none of your business. I didnt not really understand the tone of право in this sentence either

Comment: @Almonds812, Do you mean **"Да, ты права, Света, но это моё дело"?**
If yes, it means "Yes, Sveta, you're right. But thats none of your business".

Comment: Yes “права” was the word given in the sentence , i just thought it was a typo because the definition i get is authority?

Comment: **"Права"** is feminine gender of word **"прав"**. This word means **"be right"**.

Comment: Is права outdated?

Comment: **"Он прав в этом, но и она по своему права"** - **"He's right about that, but she's right too on her own way"**

Comment: No, in this meaning "прав"/"права" is not outdated. You can use it for sure,

Comment: Спасибо за все!!

Comment: "Право" is also not outdated when taken as a noun meaning "law, jurisprudence" or someone's right for something (right of free speech, etc). Also it would not be outdates when used as a middle gender for "прав" - like "Народное ополчение было право в том, что...". But in namesake-право-action pattern it has the "old books" tint.

Comment: "Права" also might be a plural for "право" noun, then would usually mean official certificate to drive cars. Unless put in a framework like "fight for your rights" giving another default context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a short answer and the question means these 3 words in the sense REALLY, here is the answer:

действительно - neutral, 
правда - colloquial,
право - very old-fashioned, hence could be ironic.

But this is relevant only when they mean REALLY.

Правда can be noun = truth, право - legal system, law.